# Reinstalling Windows and iPod Shuffle Music

Tags: itunes, ipod

I have to reinstall Windows, which means I'll lose my library. I have all of the music I want on my iPod Shuffle, however, when I reinstall iTunes and load up my iPod, will it require me to restart my iPod at square zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Back up your iTunes library](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1751) and restore it after you re-install Windows.

Don't forget about your IOS backups! [About IOS Backups](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946)